# in $R^n$, given a hyperplane $ w'x+b =0, w, x, b \in R^n$, what is the intuitive effect of scaling $w$ up or down?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm studying SVM, and I'm trying to intuit what happens when $w$ in the hyperplane $w'x+b=0$ is scaled up or down.

Comment: Are $w$ and $x$ vectors? Do you mean $\vec w \cdot \vec x+\vec b=0$?

Comment: yes, sorry, i didn't know how to put the vector arrow notation.